# Converting Quartz data from one (P3221) space group to another (P3121)

Tags: stereochemistry, crystal-structure, isomers, crystallography, x-ray-diffraction

For my studies, I’ve done a lot of work on coal fly ash QXRD QPA on TOPAS which has been a fun and interesting challenge. Apart from theory reviewing, a lot of my learning so far has come from a prior colleague of mine who had done an extensive amount of fly ash QPA.

One thing I’ve noticed in my prior colleague’s work is that he has occasionally gotten quartz .cif/.str files with a spacegroup of P3221 (left-handed quartz) and then, when loading it into a .inp file, seemingly changed the spacegroup to P3121 (right-handed quartz). Originally, I wasn’t sure why he would do this (and simplistically thought the simple right vs left-handed geometry would correct itself in a refinement) until I ran a refinement with the original .str file and had a big intensity error with my quartz. Since then, I’ve realised the massive difference alternate site positions can have which are seemingly mitigated when switching to the alternate space groups (which I presume are the quartz found in the original sample). From this, I’ve been trying to develop a model to easily convert between spacegroups as many quartz .cif/.str files I’ve seen have the former spacegroup and, obviously, I don’t want these refinement errors when I’m trying to get meaningful results out.

**So, from the above, my questions are the following:**

**1.**  Apart from significant intensity errors, how can the suitability of left vs right-handed space groups (such as with quartz) be noticed during a refinement?

**2.**  Is there a general rule when incorporating crystal enantiomorphs as to which ‘hand’ should be applied or should it be determined empirically when refining a given diffractogram?

**3.**  Are the amended site positions correct? If so, or not, can anyone provide a reference so that I can create a model to do this conversion on Python (or JEdit) before doing a refinement?

**a)**  The original .cif file (PDF database entry no. 000461045) had the following data:

```
Spacegroup: P3221

site Si_1   x 0.4723   y =0;   z =2/3;   occ Si+4 1.0   beq  0.59533
site O_1   x 0.416   y 0.2658   z  0.7881   occ O-2  1.0   beq  1.37938
```

**b)**  The final .inp file used for analysis had the following information:

```
Spacegroup: P3121

site Si num_posns  3 occ Si+4  1 beq  0.46 x  0.4698 y  0 z =1/3; :  0.33333
site O num_posns  6 occ O-2  1 beq  0.46 x  0.4151 y  0.2675 z  0.2139
```